# Facebook authentication in a UIWebView does not redirect back to original page on my site asking for auth

Tags: ios, facebook, mobile, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-login

In our iOS app, we have a UIWebView that shows web content on our domain that has a Facebook comment module. The comment module requires that the user is signed in with facebook. When user clicks on the sign in button, they are taken through the sign in flow, but are never redirect back to our page. They end up on an FB owned page that just tells the user "You are now signed in".

Repro steps:

1. Create a UIWebView in an iOS app, and host a Facebook comment module on a page hosted on some domain you own (e.g. http://foo.com/test.htm).
2. Click on the Sign In button on the comment module and notice you are redirect to FB sign in.
3. Sign in with valid FB credentials and observe what happens.

After you sign in (step 3) I would expect that after a successful authentication, you are redirected back to the original page (e.g http://foo.com/test.htm) so you can continue your interaction.  However, this isn't happening.

Instead, you are on an FB owned page that just says something like "You are now signed in" and you are trapped there. No redirect happens.

Is this indeed a bug or is there something else I should be doing to ensure the redirect happens?

Comment: Do you get the same behavior if your reproduce everything using OS X Safari?  In other words, have you confirmed this is a UIWebView issue versus an issue with the rest of your approach?  If you've confirmed that it works fine in a regular web browser, please post your code where you instantiate and loading your UIWebView so we can see what properties you are setting on it, etc.

Comment: I don't have OS X, but on Safari windows it does not repro. That is, load the page with an FB unauthenticated state, click on the comment button in the comment plugin, a new safari window pops up giving me FB login and when I login it dismisses & the original knows I'm signed in.  However, I suspect that has to do with the fact that the FB login window is in a popup when i use the desktop safari.  In an embedded UIWebView, you can't do pop ups.  In my repro steps above, you'll see that Facebook is the one that is redirected to an FB owned page with no opportunity for me to do anything.

Comment: If anyone is still looking - this worked - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34777695/815929

Answer (score 14):

If you are just supporting iOS 8 and up, you can use [`WKWebView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/) which already implements the functionality described by [@kabuko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10037870/5199788):

```
// Container view including the main WKWebView
var container : UIView?
var popupWebView : WKWebView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let prefs = WKPreferences()
    prefs.javaScriptEnabled = true
    // allow facebook to open the login popup
    prefs.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true

    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    config.preferences = prefs

    webView = WKWebView(frame: container.frame, configuration: config)
    webView?.UIDelegate = self
    webView?.navigationDelegate = self
}

// callback if the content of the webView wants to create a new window
func webView(webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWithConfiguration configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, forNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
    // create new popup webview and add it to the view hierarchy
    popupWebView = WKWebView(frame: container.frame, configuration: configuration)
    container.addSubview(popupWebView!)
    return popupWebView
}

func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    // if the main webView loads a new page (e.g. due to succesful facebook login)
    // remove the popup
    if (popupWebView != nil) {
        popupWebView?.removeFromSuperview()
        popupWebView = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: what is popupWebView here?

Comment: It is a new WKWebView instance which is generated in the method `createWebViewWithConfiguration`. This web view is used the "new window" in which the Facebook login is going to be displayed.
I am going to update the answer to make this more clear.

Comment: Thanks very much. This should be the new response as it is much easier. Just a thing, u forgot about `webView?.UIDelegate = self`

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I just added it to the code snippet.

Comment: This does NOT detect Google/Facebook/etc.. login popups/windows. I tried it and it doesn't work. It does detect basic external website links, but when pressing on the ```Login with Facebook``` button, it just loads the Facebook login page in the current ```WKWebView```. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: In regards to my last comment, this works on MOST websites. For example I was testing it out with the Feedly website and it didn't work.

Comment: @ dthulke, i have successfully created a new instance of wkwebview and loggin is successful now. After login with facebook , i have some button that share data in facebook. When click that , wkwebview createWebViewWith method is called. If i create new window/instance with the share url , it just open facebook home page. Not share view. What could be the solution for this case ?

Comment: Just a wild guess (since I do not know how your logic is working): probably there is no redirect in the newly opened window and the popup is expected to be closed somehow. Did you check whether webViewDidClose is called in the popup and do you handle this appropriately? If this does not help please open a new question.

Answer (score 8):

I've seen something similar happen with other sites' FB logins (e.g. Groupon) if you load them in a `UIWebView`. If this is the same problem (which I think it is), it *is* due to Facebook opening up the login window in a popup as you suspected. What happens on a normal browser is that another window (popup) is opened for login, and then when the user logs in, that login window communicates back to the original window to say that it has logged in. They probably use EasyXDM or something similar. There seem to be a few layers of strategies to communicate including Flash and `postMessage`.

On iOS (and Android) this should mean it'll end up communicating with `postMessage`. If you track the URLs that go through your `UIWebView` you should see something like this near the end:

```
https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php#<lots of stuff>&relation=opener&transport=postmessage&<lots more stuff>
```

`UIWebView` doesn't support multiple windows so it can't `postMessage` back to your original page since it's no longer loaded. What you can do is detect when the `UIWebView` is trying to load the FB login page and load that in a separate `UIWebView`. Now you have two windows to work with.

Unfortunately, this is still not enough as when the JavaScript on FB's page tries to run `window.opener.postMessage` or `window.parent.postMessage` it doesn't work because `window.parent` and `window.opener` aren't set to the appropriate window. I don't know of a good way to do this in iOS (in contrast Android provides a proper API for this).

The way I've worked around this is to hack up a JavaScript object to wrap these calls. Something like:

```
window.opener={};
window.opener.postMessage = function(data,url) {
    // signal your code in objective-c using some strategy
};
window.parent = window.opener;
```

There are a few ways you can call Objective-C from JavaScript including [this one from the official docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001215). You can inject this code into that static FB login page I mentioned before using [`stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:). I couldn't find a good time to do this, so I just inject it after page load and call `doFragmentSend()` which is the FB JavaScript method on that static page that normally gets called on body load.

So now all we need to do is pass on this data into the original `UIWebView` by calling `postMessage`. It'll look something like this:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.postMessage('%@', '*');", data];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:post];
```

If you haven't noticed by now, this is a huge messy hack and I probably wouldn't recommend it unless you have no alternative, but it's worked for me.

Comment: I have one question. how you enter the `window.opener={};
window.opener.postMessage = function(data,url) {
    // signal your code in objective-c using some strategy
};
window.parent = window.opener;` code to the page?

Comment: The paragraph below that code block describes how to inject that code.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I figured out, after the Facebook login the UIWebView components is empty, there is no html code within it. I solved the issue by checking the content of the UIWebView component on the webViewDidFinishLoad function and reload its content when I detect the Facebook login causes white (empty screen):

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    if ( [[webView1 stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
           @"document.body.innerHTML"] isEqualToString:@""] ) {
        [webView1 loadRequest:request]; //Define request as you want
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey I know it's an old post, but this might be the solution to my query. Can you share what to put in `request` in a line `[webView1 loadRequest:request]`. Sorry I'm new to iOS

Comment: @ShanilSoni: Did u figure out what is request??

Comment: @szpetip: Would you please mention what request is, with a sample??

Comment: @rAzOr Nope, I didn't. Please share.

Answer (score 0):

Currently in mobile, browser not supporting multiple windows by default.
The alternate solution is to monitor the successful redirect from facebook like 
"close_popup.php?reload=https://" and reloading the page.
Also make sure that you preserve the facebook comment value before login request so that it can be again put in comment box.