# Facebook Javascript login in native ios6 UIWebView (WORKS ON SAFARI)

Tags: javascript, facebook, ios6, sdk, uiwebview

I am looking for a solution about running FB.login() at a native iOS 6 app with UIWebView. I already debugged a lot and did not found the solution yet.

The problem is: When a call fb.login, my app opens a new UIWebView to handle it (like safari opens a new tab). Facebook Login appears but when it logs, a blank page appears and nothing happens (neither in root UIWebView)... anyone knows the solution to complete fb.login js flow?

Thanks guys!

PS: 
Links that does not helps--

[How can I get UIWebView to open Facebook login page in response to the OAuth request on iOS 5 and iOS 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313225/how-can-i-get-uiwebview-to-open-facebook-login-page-in-response-to-the-oauth-req)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387272/fb-login-issue-with-ios-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it!

It kinda of a hack, but the js facebook sdk login on UiWebView at iOS 6 finally works.

How it could be done? It is a pure JS + Facebook JS SDK + UIWebView Delegate handling functions solution.

JS - First step)

a login button (to connect with facebook) calls this function example, that will trigger Face JS login/oauth dialogs:

```
function loginWithFacebookClick(){

FB.login(function(response){
    //normal browsers callback 
});

}
```

JS - Second step)

add a authResponseChange listener every time user loads the webpage ( after FB.init() ) to catch user's connected status:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponse.Change', function(response){
//UIWebView login 'callback' handler
var auth = response.authResponse;
if(auth.status == 'connected'){
    //user is connected with facebook! just log him at your webapp
}
});
```

AND with app's UIWebView delegate functions you can handler facebook oauth responses

Objective C - Third step)

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
NSString *url = [[request URL] absoluteString];

//when user status == connected (has a access_token at facebook oauth response)
if([url hasPrefix:@"https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth"] && [url rangeOfString:@"access_token="].location != NSNotFound)
{
    [self backToLastPage];
    return NO;
}

return YES;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{

NSString *url = [[webView.request URL] absoluteString];

if([url hasPrefix:@"https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth"])
{
    NSString *bodyHTML = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];

    //Facebook oauth response dead end: is a blank body and a head with a script that does 
    //nothing. But if you got back to your last page, the handler of authResponseChange
    //will catch a connected status if user did his login and auth app
    if([bodyHTML isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        [self backToLastPage];
    }
}

}
```

So, when 'redirect' user to the last loaded page, the second step is going to handler user action at facebook login dialogs.

If I got too fast with this answer, please ask me!
Hope it helps.

Comment: This works for login and social plugin for comments as well. But taking websites with Facebook login in their process of registration, this won't solve the problem as you are redirecting to previous page on empty page and not on redirect url set in the Facebook app.

Comment: You must Get info from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870492/facebook-ios-sdk-login-native-and-uiwebview-login/22167103#22167103

Comment: Hi @pinthor, exactly what is doing [self backToLastPage]?

Comment: @baquiax, man this was in iOS 6 (almost 3 years ago). That I remember, this function simply calls history.back() from browser.

Comment: :D @pinthor I know it. It was only a doubt. :)

Comment: @pinthor: `backToLastPage` doesn't work anymore, right?