# Facebook iOS SDK login native and UIWebView login

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

For an app I'm working on I need the users to be able to login to Facebook using the native SDK, but there is also a separate part of the app using an FB comments widget in a webview.  The problem is after the user logs in using native SDK they are not logged in within the webview comments widget.  Is there a way to have the user login using the native iOS SDK and then also log them into Facebook in a UIWebView.  I tried using openAccessTokenFromData:completionHandler: in the FBSession class after the user signed in but couldn't get that to work, like below

```
- (void)didLogin
{
    FBAccessTokenData *data = [FBAccessTokenData createTokenFromString:[FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.accessToken
                                                       permissions:[FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.permissions
                                                    expirationDate:[FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.expirationDate
                                                         loginType:FBSessionLoginTypeWebView
                                                       refreshDate:nil];

    [[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation];

    FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] init];

    [session openFromAccessTokenData:data
               completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
               }];
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used following code to open Facebook iOs SDK login in Webview in my native app and its works fine for me.

```
-(void)openFacebookAuthentication
{
    NSArray *permission = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kFBEmailPermission,kFBUserPhotosPermission, nil];

    FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permission];

    [FBSession setActiveSession: [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permission] ];

    [[FBSession activeSession] openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {

        switch (status) {
            case FBSessionStateOpen:
                [self getMyData];
                break;
            case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed: {
                // prefer to keep decls near to their use
                // unpack the error code and reason in order to compute cancel bool
                NSString *errorCode = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:FBErrorLoginFailedOriginalErrorCode];
                NSString *errorReason = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:FBErrorLoginFailedReason];
                BOOL userDidCancel = !errorCode && (!errorReason || [errorReason isEqualToString:FBErrorLoginFailedReasonInlineCancelledValue]);


                if(error.code == 2 && ![errorReason isEqualToString:@"com.facebook.sdk:UserLoginCancelled"]) {
                    UIAlertView *errorMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:kFBAlertTitle
                                                                           message:kFBAuthenticationErrorMessage
                                                                           delegate:nil
                                                                           cancelButtonTitle:kOk
                                                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [errorMessage performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
                    errorMessage = nil;
                    }
                }
                break;
                // presently extension, log-out and invalidation are being implemented in the Facebook class
            default:
                break; // so we do nothing in response to those state transitions
        }
    }];
    permission = nil;
}
```

Comment: Cool I'll try this out soon and let you know

Comment: Sure,Let me know if you get any trouble.

Comment: This opens a webview for login and then when I go to the view controller with the uiwebview I'm already logged into facebook which is good.  The problem is that if I go to the uiwebview first and login to facebook can that data be shared back to the native sdk?

Comment: This isn't exactly what I was looking for but best solution I've seen so far, thanks

Comment: @marchinram Have you found a solution to your question about user going to web view first, then trying to login to Facebook?

Comment: Thank you thank you! It seems the FB webview is opened within the app, which then shares its session/cookies with any other webview opened in the app. Is this correct?

Comment: @DivyaBhalodiya Do you have a solution that is working in 2017? Yours was using the old SDK and is of course outdated, and using FBSDKLoginManager along with FBSDKLoginBehavior.web is not working, as I also have to login within a Webview even if I just logged using the native SDK. Please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Create facebook Appid [Facebook Appid creating link](https://developers.facebook.com/) Creating time follow facebook guide lines  you must give bundile identfier in register time [image: Give Facebook appid information in **plist** like blow image]

Then Use this Code

```
@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
@property(nonatomic,retain)UIWebView *webview;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *accessToken;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UIActivityIndicatorView  *FbActive;
@end
@interface LoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation LoginViewController
@synthesize accessToken,webview,FbActive;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

   //Removeing the UIWebview Cookies 
    NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (cookie in [storage cookies]) {
        [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


}
-(IBAction)fbLoginPage:(UIButton *)sender1
{


    NSString   *facebookClientID =facebookAppId;
    NSString   *redirectUri = @"http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
    NSString  *extended_permissions=@"user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream,offline_access,user_checkins,friends_checkins,email";

    NSString *url_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&scope=%@&type=user_agent&display=touch", facebookClientID, redirectUri, extended_permissions];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url_string];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    CGRect webFrame =[self.view frame];
    webFrame.origin.y = 0;
    UIWebView *aWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];
    [aWebView setDelegate:self];
    self.webview = aWebView;
    self.FbActive = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    self.FbActive.color=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
    self.FbActive.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2, self.view.frame.size.height / 2);
    [self.FbActive startAnimating];

    [webview loadRequest:request];
    [self.webview addSubview:self.FbActive];
    [self.view addSubview:webview];


}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)_webView {

    /**
     * Since there's some server side redirecting involved, this method/function will be called several times
     * we're only interested when we see a url like:  http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=..........
     */

    //get the url string
     [self.FbActive stopAnimating];
    NSString *url_string = [((_webView.request).URL) absoluteString];

    //looking for "access_token="
    NSRange access_token_range = [url_string rangeOfString:@"access_token="];

    //looking for "error_reason=user_denied"
    NSRange cancel_range = [url_string rangeOfString:@"error_reason=user_denied"];

    //it exists?  coolio, we have a token, now let's parse it out....
    if (access_token_range.length > 0) {

        //we want everything after the 'access_token=' thus the position where it starts + it's length
        int from_index = access_token_range.location + access_token_range.length;
        NSString *access_token = [url_string substringFromIndex:from_index];

        //finally we have to url decode the access token
        access_token = [access_token stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        //remove everything '&' (inclusive) onward...
        NSRange period_range = [access_token rangeOfString:@"&"];

        //move beyond the .
        access_token = [access_token substringToIndex:period_range.location];

        //store our request token....
        self.accessToken = access_token;

        //remove our window
//      UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
//      if (!window) {
//          window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
//      }

        [self.webview removeFromSuperview];
         self.webview=nil;



        //tell our callback function that we're done logging in :)
        //      if ( (callbackObject != nil) && (callbackSelector != nil) ) {
        //          [callbackObject performSelector:callbackSelector];
        //      }

        //the user pressed cancel

    }
    else if (cancel_range.length > 0)
    {
        //remove our window
//      UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
//      if (!window) {
//          window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
//      }

        [self.webview removeFromSuperview];
        self.webview=nil;

        //tell our callback function that we're done logging in :)
        //      if ( (callbackObject != nil) && (callbackSelector != nil) ) {
        //          [callbackObject performSelector:callbackSelector];
        //      }

    }
    [self getuserdetailes];

}

-(void)getuserdetailes
{
    NSString *action=@"me";

    NSString *url_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@?", action];

    //tack on any get vars we have...

    NSDictionary *get_vars=nil;

    if ( (get_vars != nil) && ([get_vars count] > 0) ) {

        NSEnumerator *enumerator = [get_vars keyEnumerator];
        NSString *key;
        NSString *value;
        while ((key = (NSString *)[enumerator nextObject])) {

            value = (NSString *)[get_vars objectForKey:key];
            url_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@=%@&", url_string, key, value];

        }//end while
    }//end if

    if (accessToken != nil)
    {

        //now that any variables have been appended, let's attach the access token....
        url_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@access_token=%@", url_string, self.accessToken];
        url_string = [url_string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@",url_string);
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url_string]];

        NSError *err;
        NSURLResponse *resp;
        NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&resp error:&err];
        NSString *stringResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@",stringResponse);
        NSError* error;
        NSDictionary *FBResResjson = [NSJSONSerialization
                                      JSONObjectWithData:response//1
                                      options:kNilOptions
                                      error:&error];
            NSLog(@"%@",FBResResjson);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

thank to Divya Bhalodiya answered. this is the swift 3 version with Facebook SDK 4.x. If the code has any problem, feel free to edit & comment. Hope this will help.

```
func verifyFromWebView() {
  let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
  fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.web
  fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: self) { (result, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else if (result?.isCancelled)!{
        print("Cancelled")
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else{

        if let fbLoginResult = result {
            if fbLoginResult.grantedPermissions != nil && fbLoginResult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"){

                self.getFBData()

            }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is working to let the user logs in using the native SDK, but you still have to also logs in the webview. So this solution is no longer working to fix OP problem.