# Android Webview and Facebook Login Not working

Tags: android, facebook, webview, android-webview

I am having a problem with a `WebView` app that I am working on.

We have this responsive website that is being displayed through an android `WebView`.

The website has a **Sign in with Facebook** option, this works fine in a mobile browser and on the website itself. Whenever I try to use the `WebView` app to login using `Facebook`, it results in a white screen.

I am having difficulties finding a solution to get this to work.

Appreciate any advise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making facebook login work with an Android Webview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648099/making-facebook-login-work-with-an-android-webview)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was able to find a solution based on a previous question on stackoverflow.com

[Making facebook login work with an Android Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648099/making-facebook-login-work-with-an-android-webview)

Here is a link to my MainActivity : http://pastebin.com/KdzfhqDJ

Comment: Do we have to install Facebook android SDK for the `login with facebook` to work in webview app??

Comment: @rAzOr You don't need to do install facebook sdk for that.

Comment: Hi, @Gayan I tried your code, I get two errors 1. error: cannot find symbol variable progressBar and error: cannot find symbol variable menu how can I fix these?

Comment: I took them out and I launched the app...but when I click to login. I get a white screen with 1? Any help will be appreciated. @IsaacKingston

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly certain it's this [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025082/facebook-authentication-in-a-uiwebview-does-not-redirect-back-to-original-page-o/10037870#10037870). Essentially it opens in another window and `WebView` doesn't support multiple windows out-of-the-box.

Luckily for you, unlike that question which was iOS-specific, if I recall correctly, it's possible to extend `WebView` to support multiple windows. You'll need to extend `WebChromeClient`, implement [`onCreateWindow`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onCreateWindow%28android.webkit.WebView,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20android.os.Message%29) and use it in your `WebView`.

Comment: Thanks @kabuko . I found a solution. Will post in a min.

Comment: @GayanHewa Can you please post your solution?

Comment: @IsaacKingston I have the link to the script on the post

Comment: My bad missed it! Thanks for replying though.