# Android app with multiple package names won't work with Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, google-play, amazon-appstore

Facebook's API allows only one Android package name

But a game may be named

com.studio.GameForGooglePlayStore
for Google Play
and
com.studio.GameForAmazonAppStore
for Amazon App Store

How could this work with Facebook?

(The reason for having different package name is to prevent Google Play from accidentally updating an app that was originally installed from Amazon App Store for example. This would switch the app store from Amazon to Google for the app user, resulting in a confusing experience)

Comment: Use separate facebook app in developer console. Or you can use web-based login using Android WebView. You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23790231/android-webview-and-facebook-login-not-working

Comment: I'm referring to the part where FB asks what is your app's package name, probably to associate with your FB app id. FB only allows one name.

Comment: @Md.TahmidMozaffar I can't use a separate app. Being the same game, FB will likely reject it. And to clarify, this question is not about login. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same Package Name, and different signing keys. Google Play won't update an app signed with Amazon's key, and vice-versa. Using different package names is not necessary

Comment: We are supporting Samsung Galaxy apps. The platform requires all submitted builds to have a different package name than the same app on Google Play.

For the signing keys suggestion, we have tried and ran into other issues and cannot use it. Though due to the mentioned platform requiring different package name, different signing key is unfortunately not an option.