# Facebook autentication in a web view does not redirect to the original page in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, web, view, modal-dialog

Now I am building iOS app and I have unresolved problem.
It is following;
As I mentioned above in the title, I can't login through Facebook.

For that;
1. I created the web view A(shown any site) providing the functionality of FB login.
2. And then I had another webviewB programmatically (shown FB login view)

I can get the FB login info in webviewB.
and then I have to login any site with FB login info.But I can't.
Please help me.

In Android, I can use the setchromeclient() Or setWebviewClient().
but I can't in iOS.

I think the UIWebview has not enough func as Safari.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use webview directly for facebook authentication.

For getting communicated with facebook for its data(Authentication in your case) you have to use either of the options

1. [Apple's Social framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Social/Reference/SLRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SLRequest)
2. [Facebook iOS SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/)

By using this way the framework will handle the redirection after authentication

Facebook iOS SDK provided by facebook is much more flexible.

Comment: but I want the correct answer about this problem"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025082/facebook-authentication-in-a-uiwebview-does-not-redirect-back-to-original-page-o".